# php multidimension array values to variables

Tags: php, arrays, variables

I'm overlooking something but I've tried everything I can think of to get these values into variables.

Existing array is created like this:
    $compdata[] = array($currentTime,$indiff,$outdiff,$totaldiff);

And this is the dump of the array:

```
Array (   
[0] => Array ( [0] => 1385955600 [1] => 29749073 [2] => 116376416 [3] => 146125489 )  
[1] => Array ( [0] => 1385956200 [1] => 2628480405 [2] => 18073170501 [3] => 20701650906 )   
[3] => Array ( [0] => 1385957400 [1] => 2728527955 [2] => 16495107227 [3] => 19223635182 )  
)
```

My question is how to get these values with a foreach or while loop into variables like:

```
$time = $value[0];  
$inbound = $value[1];  
$outbound = $value[2];  
$total = $value[3];
```

I know I have to do something to get the nested values. . . .

Much appreciated.

Comment: Are you looking to concatenate the values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're literally just missing the loop:

```
foreach ($compdata as $value) {
    $time = $value[0];  
    $inbound = $value[1];  
    $outbound = $value[2];  
    $total = $value[3]; 
}
```

Comment: Perfect.  Thank you.  My dumb question certainly deserves the down vote and your clear answer deserves many up votes.  Actually I had tried combinations of the loop, but in my test script I echoed the variables outside of the right curly and obviously it only returned the first result.  Once I moved the echo inside of the loop, all is well.  It's kind of like I was deer hunting in a field full of bunnies and all I could see was bunnies.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using [list](http://www.php.net/list), as

```
foreach ($compdata as $array) 
    {
    list($time,$inbound,$outbound,$total)=$array;

    }
```